# prevent duplication insert without insert ignore

Tags: mysql

I have this insert condition

```
tx_id | tx_date             | tx_status
001   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | y
002   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | y
```

I want to insert same tx_id and tx_date again when tx_status is 'n', and silently prevent when tx_status is 'y'.

The below is allowed:

```
tx_id | tx_date             | tx_status
001   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | n
002   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | n
001   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | y
002   | 2021-08-11 00:00:00 | y
```

not able to use `unqiue key` with `insert ignore into`, because the tx_id, tx_date, tx_status values can be duplicate.

I just want to prevent double entry for the same tx_id, tx_date and tx_status.

Comment: You could do it by adding a ```UNIQUE``` triple index key on all of three columns

Comment: @FarhadRad used ADD UNIQUE KEY, but it prompted Duplicate entry.

Comment: Write a stored procedure that checks for the existence of a given `tx_id`, `tx_date`, and `tx_status='y'`, and if such a record does not exist (or if the given `tx_status != 'y'`) then insert it.